# Creating scrollable list with python and PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a QScrollArea with a QWidget (content_widget) inside in my application. I want to fill it with images while the application is running. I would like to have the scroll behavior if the number of images exceeds the number which can be shown without scrolling. I came this far:

```
children_occupied_width = self.ui.content_widget.childrenRect().width()

image_view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.ui.content_widget)
image_view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect( children_occupied_width, 0, 210, 210 ))
image_view.setObjectName("New Image")

placeholder_image = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
placeholder_image.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('placeholder.png'))
image_view.setScene(placeholder_image)

image_view.show()
```

Although the images appear in the list at the right position there is no scrolling if the images start to be placed outside of the visible area. The size of content_widget seems not to change even with

```
self.ui.content_widget.resize(...)
```

or

```
self.ui.content_widget.adjustSize()
```

How to make it grow/resize?

Comment: A QGraphicsView has its own scroll functionality for the scene it is viewing. Any reason you are not just using that?

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to show a collection of images, not a large single one.

Comment: It does not matter what exactly is in the scene. 1 image. 100 images. Technically you can just use the scroll bars on the graphics view. Its more work to disable them and have to correlate the size up to another widget.

Comment: OK, the approach to put all images in one QGraphicsView is a way I haven't thought about.

Comment: How were you arranging them before?

Comment: As described: one Image per QGraphicsView placed in a QWidget which acts as the content widget of the QScrollArea.

Comment: Does each image need special interaction abilities like independently zooming and translating? I'm curious as to the usage of many individual QGraphicsView widgets over a grid of QLabels

Comment: No, I just show an image with a name and a button.

Comment: QGraphics is overkill for this. Use QLabels in a QVBoxLayout. I think you were overcomplicating this whole solution for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least a reason why `resize` did not worked in my code. Setting `widgetResizable` property of QScroll area to false (or disabling it in the Qt Designer) made it work.

Answer (score 1):

*This first part turned out to not be what you really needed. I am leaving it for informational purposes, but see the update at the bottom*

The problem is that the QGraphicsView is itself a type of scroll widget, representing a slice of the scene it is viewing. Ideally you would just use the view by itself and make use of its own scrollbars.

But if you have specific need to forward the content size of the view up to a normal QWidget scroll, then what you would need to do is make your QGraphicsView always resize itself when the contents of the scene change. The QScrollArea is only going to respond to size changes of the widget it is set to. The view needs to change size. The process would be that the view needs to listen to signals from the scene for added or removed items, and then resize itself to completely enclose all of those children.

Here is an example of how the QGraphicsView widget, on its own, is perfectly capable of serving as the scroll functionality:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)

view.resize(600,300)

pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")

w,h = pix.width(), pix.height()
x = y = 0
pad = 5
col = 3

for i in xrange(1,20):
    item = scene.addPixmap(pix)
    item.setPos(x,y)

    if i % col == 0:
        x = 0
        y += h+pad
    else:
        x+=w+pad

view.show()
view.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

You can see that when the images overflow the current size of the view, you get scrollbars.
If you really need to have some parent scroll area acting as the scroll for the view (for reasons I do not really understand), then here is a more complex example showing how you would need to watch for some event on the scene and then constantly update the size of the view to force scrollbars on the parent scrollarea. I have chosen to watch a signal on the scene for when its rect changes (more children are added)

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = QtGui.QDialog()
win.resize(600,300)
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(win)
scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
layout.addWidget(scroll)

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scroll)
view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(scroll)
view.setScene(scene)

scroll.setWidget(view)

pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")

w,h = pix.width(), pix.height()
x = y = i = 0
pad = 5
col = 3

def createImage():
    global x,y,i
    item = scene.addPixmap(pix)
    item.setPos(x,y)

    i+=1
    if i % col == 0:
        x = 0
        y += h+pad
    else:
        x+=w+pad

def changed():
    size = scene.itemsBoundingRect().size()
    view.setMinimumSize(size.width()+pad, size.height()+pad)

scene.changed.connect(changed)

t = QtCore.QTimer(win)
t.timeout.connect(createImage)
t.start(500)

win.show()
win.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

The scroll area is always looking at the size of the widget that has set as the child. The view must be resized.

**Update**

As it turns out from your comments, you didn't really need to use the QGraphics objects for this approach. It only made your task more complicated. Simply use a vertical layout and add QLabel widgets to it:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = QtGui.QDialog()
win.resize(300,300)
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(win)
scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
layout.addWidget(scroll)

scrollContents = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(scrollContents)
scroll.setWidget(scrollContents)

pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")

def createImage():
    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    label.setPixmap(pix)
    layout.addWidget(label)

t = QtCore.QTimer(win)
t.timeout.connect(createImage)
t.start(500)

win.show()
win.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem. But how to change the size of the widget?

Comment: My example shows how to have the QGraphicsView constantly resized by the signal connection to when the scene changes

Comment: Thanks, may be I can use this some day.

Comment: I was completely thrown off by your usage of QGraphics. I didn't realize that all you really needed was a vertical layout containing a bunch of QLabel's